# How to create a list and when you click on one of its members it moves it to the list of favorites

Tags: flutter

I want something like a list so that when I press on a button, the list item moves to another list called Favorites.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, please visit the help center and read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** a long with the other topics there, and **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52028900/edit)** your question to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in one of the Flutter getting started Codelabs. Check [Link](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a very broad question, so I'll describe some general guidelines:**

First, make sure you got a basic understanding of Flutter's widgets model. For this, there are several videos on YouTube or Codelabs by Google.

The next step would be to think about state management.
At Google I/O there was an [example of a Shopping Cart app](https://youtu.be/RS36gBEp8OI?t=11m56s) that pretty much resembles your requirements.
You may also want to check out the [source code of that app on Github](https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments).